# Why Can I not resolve docker.io and other hosts behind proxy from within Vagrant VM

Tags: proxy, vagrant, virtualbox, docker, boot2docker

I am running Vagrant with 2 docker containers inside and it works fine when not on a corporate proxy but When I am on the corporate proxy and try to run vagrant up I keep getting :

```
https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/dockerfile/ubuntu/images: 
dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: no such host
```

I have the proxy set inside vagrant using

```
VAGRANT_HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8080/" vagrant up
```

I also cannot get it to resolve hosts using `nslookup` within vagrant on the corporate proxy

I have tried including the following within the vagrantfile as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901859/cannot-make-outbound-http-requests-from-vagrant-vm):

```rb
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
end
```

I have also tried using a bridged connection, restarting the docker server as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493920/docker-containers-not-using-host-dns-in-boot2docker) and swapping my DNS on my mac (which I saw suggested somewhere else but cannot find link)

I would really appreciate some help/direction, and in case its relavent I am running vargrant 1.6.5 on a macbook running OSX 10.9 with virtual box and this is my vagrant file:

```rb
$start = <<SCRIPT
#service docker stop
#HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:8080/ docker -d &
service docker restart

#stop and remove any existing containers
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

echo "Building from Dockerfiles"
# Build containers from Dockerfiles
docker build -t sapvagrant/web_app /var/local/app/webApp
docker build -t sapvagrant/node /var/local/app/nodeService

echo "Running & linking containers"
# Run and link the containers
docker run -d --name node myvagrant/node
docker run -d -P -p 49166:80 --name web --link node:db myvagrant/web_app

docker start node
docker start web
SCRIPT

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

=begin
    if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
        config.proxy.http     = "http://proxy:8080/"
        config.proxy.https    = "http://proxy:8080/"
        config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
    end
=end
    #config.vm.network :bridged
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        #vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
        #vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    end

    # Port Forwarding
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 49166, host: 3000

    # Ubuntu
    config.vm.box = "precise64"
    config.vm.box_url="http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

    # Install latest docker
    config.vm.provision "docker"

    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/local/app" #, type: "nfs"
    config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "/etc/init.d/docker restart"

    #config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setup

    config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: $start

end
```

Comment: @chris-snow I don't understand what you actually edited

Comment: I added [syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to the code blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to resolve names on the Internet because your proxy server resolves the names. But vagrant-proxyconf does not configure the proxy if no docker is installed. You have 2 ways to resolve this problem.

## Configure the proxy before docker provision

[Vagrant docker provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html) cannot change configuration file. (eg. `/etc/default/docker`, `/etc/sysconfig/docker`)
You need to configure the proxy before provisioning with shell provisioner as follows.

```
  # If you use RHEL write to /etc/sysconfig/docker
  config_proxy = 'echo export http_proxy=$http_proxy >> /etc/default/docker'
  config.vm.provision('shell',
                      inline: config_proxy)
  config.vm.provision 'docker'
```

I simplified your `Vagrantfile`.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-proxyconf')
    config.proxy.http     = 'http://proxy:8080/'
    config.proxy.https    = 'http://proxy:8080/'
    config.proxy.no_proxy = 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/var/local/app'

  # Ubuntu
  config.vm.box = 'precise64'
  config.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box'

  # If you use RHEL write to /etc/sysconfig/docker
  config_proxy = 'echo export http_proxy=$http_proxy >> /etc/default/docker'
  config.vm.provision('shell',
                      inline: config_proxy)
  config.vm.provision 'docker' do |d|
    d.build_image '/var/local/app/webApp',      args: '-t sapvagrant/web_app'
    d.build_image '/var/local/app/nodeService', args: '-t sapvagrant/node'
    d.run 'sapvagrant/node',    args: '--name node'
    d.run 'sapvagrant/web_app', args: '-P -p 49166:80 --name web --link node:db'
  end
end
```

## Use docker installed VM box

Vagrant-proxyconf does not configure the proxy if no docker is installed. Vagrant-proxyconf configure the proxy if you use docker installed VM box.

- Note:

  - Vagrant-proxyconf 1.4.0 restarts docker always, so sometimes docker containers can be broken.
  - Vagrant-proxyconf 1.4.2(not released on 22nd Dec. 2014) restarts docker only when the proxy configuration changed.

You can find docker installed VM boxes on the ATLAS. I have found jess/ubuntu-precise-nginx-docker.

I simplified your `Vagrantfile`.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-proxyconf')
    config.proxy.http     = 'http://proxy:8080/'
    config.proxy.https    = 'http://proxy:8080/'
    config.proxy.no_proxy = 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/var/local/app'

  # Ubuntu
  config.vm.box = 'jess/ubuntu-precise-nginx-docker'

  config.vm.provision 'docker' do |d|
    d.build_image '/var/local/app/webApp',      args: '-t sapvagrant/web_app'
    d.build_image '/var/local/app/nodeService', args: '-t sapvagrant/node'
    d.run 'sapvagrant/node',    args: '--name node'
    d.run 'sapvagrant/web_app', args: '-P -p 49166:80 --name web --link node:db'
  end
end
```